# rm(list = ls()) on 64GB then Error: cannot allocate vector of size 11.6 Gb when trying a decision tree

Tags: r, memory

I'm trying to run a decision tree via caret package. I start my script fresh by removing everything from memory with `rm(list = ls())` then I load my training data which is 3M rows and 522 features. R studio doesn't show the size in gb but presumably by the error message it's 11.6.

If I'm using 64gb R then is it expected I see this error? Is there any way around it without resorting to training on smaller data?

```
rm(list = ls())
library(tidyverse)
library(caret)
library(xgboost)

# read in data
training_data <- readRDS("/home/myname/training_data.rds")
```

R studio environment pane currently shows one object, training data with the dims mentioned above.

```
### Modelling
# tuning & parameters
set.seed(123)
train_control <- trainControl(
  method = "cv",
  number = 5,
  classProbs = TRUE, # IMPORTANT!
  verboseIter = TRUE,
  allowParallel = TRUE
)

# Fit a decision tree (minus cad field)
print("begin decision tree regular")
mod_decitiontree <- train(
  cluster ~.,
  tuneLength = 5,
  data = select(training_data, -c(cad, id)), # a data frame
  method = "rpart",
  trControl = train_control,
  na.action = na.pass
)

Loading required package: rpart
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 11.6 Gb
```

I could ask our admin to increase my RAM but before doing that want to make sure I'm not missing something. Don't I have lot's of RAM available if I'm on 64 GB?

Do I have any options? I tried making my data frame a matrix and passing that to caret instead but it threw an error. Is passing a matrix instead a worthwhile endevour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your error message reproduced:

> cannot allocate vector of size 11.6 Gb when trying a decision tree

This means that the specific failure happened when R requested another 11.6 GB of memory, and was unable to do so.  However, the random forest calculation itself may require many such allocations, and, most likely, the remainder of free RAM was already being used.

I don't know the details of your calculation, but I would say that even running random forests on a 1GB data set is already very large.  My advice would be to find a way to take a statistically accurate sub sample of your data set such that you don't need such large numbers of RAM.

Comment: Hi thanks for the info. If I was to ask our admin for more RAM is there a way to infer approximatley how much more I need? Would passing a matrix instead of a data frame help?

Comment: @DougFir You're going to need to figure out how the memory requirements for Caret's random forest calculation correlate with the size of the input data etc.  But, as my answer suggests, I don't think you should need so much memory.

Comment: Do you need all 522 features?  Do you need 3 million rows?

Comment: RE the features, this is text data and it's pretty sparse, mostly 0's. I think I do need them though since a single feature (token) with value 1 might be all the difference in classifying

Comment: Hmm...if you're doing text classification have you considered using something like support vector machines?

Comment: No but thanks for the tip I'll take a look. For interest I'm classifying pre clustered data: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/301075/kmeans-to-assign-clusters-to-new-data-bad-practice

Comment: So is the response binary in nature, e.g. each document either is, or is not, talking about organic food?  Or maybe you could clarify this to me.

Comment: Actually there are 125 labels (I clustered with k = 125). I chose a finer number of clusters since I'm really trying to get more accurate and I'm optimistic that my clusters look promising. This is because, for each of the 125 clusters I extracted the top 10 features in that cluster and there really does seem to be good definition behind them. So, I'm hoping my classification model can translate that into higher accuracy as I try to predict the cluster based on the text based features. Someone also suggested knn. Right now so far I'm trying decision tree (just a simple baseline)...

Comment: ...(cont)  XGBoost (the one I'm most optimistic for) and knn.

Comment: Your question really belongs on Cross Validated +1, but as for getting random forests to run, I think you're going to need to pare down the size of your data set.

Comment: Got it, thanks for the info there's a sense of relief in that since it's straight forwards to just take a e.g. 500k or 1M sample rather than jump through hoops to get around memory

Comment: One more point: If you get rf working with, say a 10% random subsample, then you could try running again with a different sample and see if things change dramatically.  My guess is that they won't, but you would be the judge of that.